# SSRS Report column percentage formatting not displaying correctly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

I've recently been made aware by one of my colleagues that a report that I have created does not show percentage column values correctly when viewed on a mobile device. When viewed via desktop, either directly in the report viewer or exported to Excel the values display as expected. Does anyone know what might be causing this and if there are any potential ways to resolve this?

Please see screenshots attached which display the difference between what can be seen on mobile vs desktop (exported to Excel).

[Mobile Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDffc.png)
[Desktop (Excel) Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuJm8.png)

Unsure if this is local to one user or everyone, for the most part users will be using our reports via PCs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default programme to render SSRS reports as Excel attachment displays the format of certain data types oddly on mobile devices. This has since been resolved via a workaround - by opening the excel files using the Microsoft 365 app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).